# PowerShell background jobs (multiple .cmd files at the same time)

Tags: powershell, background-process

I'm trying to synchronize different tasks at the same the time in PowerShell because they each take around 2-4 hours. The Script i have right now just processes each task one after another. I know there is an option called *background jobs* in PowerShell. Is there a way to transform the following code so it processes multiple .cmd files at the same time?

```
$handler_button1_Click= 
{
$answer= $finalcheck.popup("text",0,"text",4)
If($answer-eq 6) {
   [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("text", "Information", [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)
   $listBox1.Items.Clear();    
    if ($checkBox1.Checked)    { 
    Try{ 
    & K:\sample.cmd
    }catch [System.Exception]{
    $listBox1.Items.Add("Error")}
    }

    if ($checkBox2.Checked)    { 
    Try{ 
    & K:\sample2.cmd
    }catch [System.Exception]{
    $listBox1.Items.Add("Error")}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Start-Job:

```
$job = Start-Job { & K:\sample.cmd }
```

At this point you are likely to need to add some code to watch the state of jobs you've started. Potentially you can periodically inspect $job.State.

Extending on this, you might refuse to start a job of the same type if one is already running.

In addition to Start-Job you should take a look at:

- Get-Job - To get any jobs (running or otherwise)
- Receive-Job - To get results back
- Remove-Job - To remove a job once you're finished with it.
- Stop-Job - To stop the job if you need to kill it.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to check if a Job has finished? Like when i start sample.cmd the process goes on for ~3 hours and it inserts files into my Oracle database. I would like to print out a message to the user, everytime a job has been finished.

Comment: Yep, you inspect $job.State, that will be Running, Completed, Failed, etc, etc.